# setting usb port to write only on linux

Tags: linux, security, usb

How would I go about disabling reading from usb sticks but still have the ability to write to them?
The reasoning is this is a public internet access (kiosk more or less) computer but we want the user to be able save files to a usb stick but not have the ability to save files to the machine or execute files from the usb stick.

Thank you

Comment: Interesting problem: the USB drives are auto-mounted, so you'd have to work out how that happens, and whether you can configure a mount in write-only mode.

Comment: I never thought it would be possible to even have write-only storage (because you need to read the filesystem and all that stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd leave the USB stick read-write (as that makes a lot of sense), but I'd set your machine's partitions to read-only.  If you lock down X enough (prevent anyone from opening a shell via xterm, for example), then it should be a piece of cake.

Some notes :
mount /var as a ramdisk?
use noexec to prevent exection of binaries

It might be easier to just chroot execute the browser, with the USB-stick mounted under the chrooted jail.

Comment: i think that's what we will do..

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html

exec and noexec exec lets you execute binaries that are on that partition, whereas noexec doesn't let you do that. noexec might be useful for a partition that contains binaries you don't want to execute on your system, or that can't even be executed on your system. This might be the case of a Windows partition.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you control the USB sticks, write-only isn't going to work well. You're going to end up with all sorts of support issues and grousing by your users.

If I were you, I would setup the kiosks to run as dumb LTSP terminals, and start the users with a completely clean environment with every session. There are all sorts of ways to do this... my college had an XTerminal lab running on some ancient Unix back in 1994.